# Tomcat 9 not using correct instance of MessageDigestCredentialHandler for WebApp

Tags: java, security, basic-authentication, tomcat9

## The Problem...

I have a web app been built in Tomcat 9, which has a local `realm` defined, with a `MessageDigestCredentialHandler`, currently set to use `MD5`.

I have a resource contained within a `security-constraint` configured to use `BASIC` authentication.

When attempting to access this resource, authentication fails.

I original had thought that the method I was using to encode the credentials was mismatching with `MessageDigestCredentialHandler`, but even after using the command line tool to generate the secret, I still could not authenticate against the resource.

After 2 days of trial and error, I pulled the source for Tomcat and added a bunch of additional logging around the realm and `MessageDigestCredentialHandler` classes, as the logged information was next to useless.

This is when I discovered that Tomcat is not only creating a number of instances of `MessageDigestCredentialHandler`, some which are not been configured with the `algorithm`, when attempting to authenticate against the resource, it's using one of the "un-configured" instances, so it's not using any digests.

### The question...

My question is basically, how do I configure Tomcat correctly to use the correct instance of the `MessageDigestCredentialHandler` and make use of the configured `algorithm`?

### Note...

This issue has been discovered while deploying the App through Netbeans during development. I've not tried this by simply manually deploying the App to Tomcat

I was originally testing this with a iOS App and verified that the `authorisation` headers were been sent/received correctly.  But I switched to pointing my browser at it the protected URL and get the same results

### Configuration...

#### `context.xml`

The `context.xml` file is stored within the `META-INF` directory of the web app, so it's defining a "web app only" configuration.

```
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
             dataSourceName="jdbc/mysql"
             userTable="logins" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="password"
             userRoleTable="login_roles" roleNameCol="role_name"
             localDataSource="true"/>
        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" 
                         algorithm="md5" />
    </Realm>
</Context>
```

#### `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.api.shoutout.UserServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/v1/user/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>Shoutout</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/mysql</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Authorised users</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/api/v1/user/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>application-user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint> 
    </security-constraint>
    <!-- Define the Login Configuration for this Application -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>application-user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

## TL;DR

The following is a cut down version of the logs

```
// Seems to be Tomcats "global" instance, but I never define any others
04-Nov-2018 07:56:48.003 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.<init> 965586344 Created
// Not sure why there is another, could be one of the other default web apps?
04-Nov-2018 07:56:48.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.<init> 660339123 Created

// Deployment of my web app (from Netbeans)
04-Nov-2018 07:56:48.022 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/Users/swhitehead/bin/tomcat/9.0.12/conf/Catalina/localhost/shoutout.xml]
// This seems to be the "correctly" created instance, 1990385139 is the hashcode of the instance
04-Nov-2018 07:56:48.192 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.<init> 1990385139 Created
04-Nov-2018 07:56:48.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.setAlgorithm 1990385139:  algorithm = md5

// Not sure where this one is coming from
04-Nov-2018 07:56:48.458 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.<init> 1307950260 Created

// This seems to be the "manager" web app
04-Nov-2018 07:56:53.912 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke Security checking request GET /manager/text/
04-Nov-2018 07:56:58.473 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate Attempting to authenticate user [development] with realm [org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm]
04-Nov-2018 07:56:58.474 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.matches inputCredentials = development; storedCredentials = development
04-Nov-2018 07:56:58.475 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.matches 965586344:  No digest
04-Nov-2018 07:56:58.476 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate Authenticated user [development] with realm [org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm]
04-Nov-2018 07:56:58.477 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.register Authenticated 'development' with type 'BASIC'
04-Nov-2018 07:56:58.477 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Calling accessControl()
04-Nov-2018 07:56:58.477 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasResourcePermission   Checking roles GenericPrincipal[development(admin,manager-script,)]
04-Nov-2018 07:56:58.477 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasRole Username [development] has role [manager-script]
04-Nov-2018 07:56:58.478 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasResourcePermission Role found:  manager-script
04-Nov-2018 07:56:58.478 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Successfully passed all security constraints

04-Nov-2018 07:56:59.207 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/Users/swhitehead/bin/tomcat/9.0.12/conf/Catalina/localhost/shoutout.xml]
// Not are why we're creating another instance, but's configured correctly
04-Nov-2018 07:56:59.217 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.<init> 341501024 Created
04-Nov-2018 07:56:59.218 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.setAlgorithm 341501024:  algorithm = md5

// Not are why we're creating another instance, but's NOT configured correctly
04-Nov-2018 07:56:59.238 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.<init> 226693907 Created

// GET protected resource
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.863 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke Security checking request GET /shoutout/api/v1/user
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.864 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Authorised users]' against GET /api/v1/user --> true
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.864 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Authorised users]' against GET /api/v1/user --> true
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.864 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.864 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasUserDataPermission   User data constraint has no restrictions
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.864 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Calling authenticate()
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.864 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate Attempting to authenticate user [bob@bob.com] with realm [org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm]
// Right here, the input credentials are not digested?!
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.935 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.matches inputCredentials = bob; storedCredentials = 8cf01ac5dc19fcbe725508aa120866d06755f8ab49170da6665537b90e6643bd$1$8419474f1f82bbb5ae4612c4a3624037
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.935 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler.matches 226693907:  No digest
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.935 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate Failed to authenticate user [bob@bob.com] with realm [org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm]
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.936 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Failed authenticate() test
```

So, from above, Tomcat is creating 4 instances of the `MessageDigestCredentialHandler`, two seem to be getting created for the web app, one with and one without the `algorithm`.

When requesting authentication, Tomcat is using the "unconfigured" instance (instance **226693907** in this case)

From one of the other logs, this checking to make sure that the connection to the database and the query been used are correct...

```
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.864 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.open >>>
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.864 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.open localDataSource
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.864 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.open dataSourceName = jdbc/mysql
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.900 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.open We are connected
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.900 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.authenticate userName = bob@bob.com; password = bob
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.900 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.getPassword getPassword
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.900 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.credentials preparedCredentials = SELECT password FROM logins WHERE user_name = ?
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.935 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.getPassword dbCredentials = 8cf01ac5dc19fcbe725508aa120866d06755f8ab49170da6665537b90e6643bd$1$8419474f1f82bbb5ae4612c4a3624037
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.935 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.authenticate bob == 8cf01ac5dc19fcbe725508aa120866d06755f8ab49170da6665537b90e6643bd$1$8419474f1f82bbb5ae4612c4a3624037 = false
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.935 FINER [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.authenticate Username [bob@bob.com] NOT successfully authenticated
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.936 FINE [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=401, location=null]
04-Nov-2018 08:04:49.936 SEVERE [http-nio-9090-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom Custom error page [null] could not be dispatched correctly
```

You can see that the digest is been pulled from the database correctly, but the input has NOT been digested!?

### Additionally...

I did a file scan of my Tomcat installation and verified that there are no other instances of `MessageDigestCredentialHandler` defined in any of the other, default, web apps or any other `.xml` based configuration files